# Can i use vga and dvi on board together.?

Tags: vga

I have both VGA and DVI port on my asus P8H61-M LE motherboard.
I want to use 2 monitors together one from VGA port and one from DVI port.
I've tried to use DVI to VGA converter.
I've connected both monitors, but it only shows display on one screen and in display option it does not detect the second screen.
How can I use both monitors?

---

Am using windows 8.1
and my drivers are intel HD graphics on board and it is uptodate.
And i have tried many times with dvi to vga converter but its not detecting screen.
i have enabled multi screen option in bios as well..
and still not getting the screen on.
what should i do now?
should i bring a dvi to dvi cable and try again.?

Comment: Update your drivers as you should be able to use both monitors simultaneously. Using a DVI-to-VGA adapter should pose no problem, either.

Comment: "DVI to VGA" might be your problem. *Generally* when there's a VGA port there's no need for a DVI port to be DVI-I - they're typically DVI-D . A clear picture of your back panel would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, connecting monitors on both DVI and VGA should work. Can you try connecting the DVI without VGA adapter and see what happens? Also go in BIOS settings and check if both VGA and DVI ports are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to do this.

You just need to configure secondary monitor display in Graphics Properties.
Since you didn't told what OS are you using I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only answer here is to check the manual.

I have used both VGA and DVI from a card.  I have also not been able to use both VGA and DVI from a card.  They may have separate video hardware behind them and behave fine when you use both of them.  They also may be two ports accessing the same hardware and not be able to coexist.  I've even seen both situations on the same card--multiple VGA ports, one of which was shared with a DVI.